# Ruby stripe api not firing events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, stripe.net

I've successfully integrated stripe.com payment with my website.

However I'm not sure why it doesn't fire events in the localhost.

Here is my stripe initializer :

```
StripeEvent.setup do
  subscribe 'charge.succeeded' do |event|
    ap 'weeeeeeeeeeeeeee'
  end

  subscribe do |event|
    # Handle all event types - logging, etc.
    ap "!got events"
    ap "#{event.inspect}"
    ap "#{event.type}"
  end
end
```

None of these fire, when I make the test payment. I'm using [stripe-event](https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event) gem

Anyone experiencing similar issues?

**UPDATE**

I am using ultrahook for request forwarding to localhost

Comment: How are you triggering events against localhost?

Comment: Can you post the server logs (`rails s`) from localhost for the webhook requests? That will help in debugging.

Comment: Still having trouble?

Comment: nop is all good now, it wasn't strip-event issue my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My actual problem wasn't with stripe-event gem, but rather with ultrahook forwarding requests to wrong destination.

I was forwarding to `localhost:5000`, instead of to `localhost:5000/stripe` so instead `ultrahook stripe 5000` I used `ultrahook stripe 5000/stripe`